# How do you start writing your API for an MCU peripheral?

Tags: embedded, stm32

I am trying to improve on my embedded programming skills by learning how to program each peripheral on an STM32 Nucleo board (STM32F401RE) and slowly building my own library from scratch (Without using HAL initially just toggling bits directly on the registers).

I am facing a problem though, when I try to encounter something that I haven't used before I am getting stuck on figuring what to include on the API.

Let's say that I want to use the ADC peripheral, is it enough to just copy the API from the mbed-src on github and start from there, or am I going to need any extra functions?

https://github.com/mbedmicro/mbed/blob/03fff9249b0ca5efb2e12506ce8fb3e6cc258d9d/libraries/mbed/targets/hal/TARGET_STM/TARGET_STM32F4XX/analogin_api.c

Are there any universally accepted resources from where to start from?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: the datasheet/users guide/programmers reference manual for the mcu

Comment: Even though I don't disagree, I have to admit that I can't find something really conclusive when reading the reference manual for the aforementioned board. The NXP LPC1768 user manual is much more helpful in my opinion but still not very clear.

Comment: The STM32 documentation is neither better nor worse than other companies' (including NXP) documentation. Problem is there are quite some places you have to experiment and which do not allow all freedom one would actually expect. However, it is at least understandable and better structured than the Freescale K-Series documentation.

Comment: Your problem is that you don't have a _problem_. The trick to decent API design is figuring out what problem you or your users actually want to solve with it, and then writing a library tailored to suit those needs. Otherwise you're liable to end up with yet another over-generalized and hard-to-debug debug monstrosity which still doesn't achieve what you want once you end up actually using it somewhere down the line.

Comment: If you think NXP docus are not clear try to fight with MX6SX Freescale's doc. You'll change your opinion ;)

Comment: Where I am coming from is, take natural steps.  If you want to learn to program the thing a the bare metal layer, then do that...THEN...when you have acquired enough knowledge and code you can design a library and an api from that knowledge.  making the api first before you know how to program the thing is putting the cart before the horse.  If you are just going to take an existing api, and tweak it then are you actually learning how it works?  using existing code is great to learn how but you still need to do the work, otherwise just use someone elses api/library.

Comment: So my answer to how do you start writing an api, is you worry about the api until later, learn about the guts of the thing the api hides, then design the api.  What is the usually accepted resource?  it is always the vendor of the ip or silicon, unless you actually work there and have access to the engineers, that is the best you are going to get.  often there is code to go along with that and that is your second best usually accepted resource.  third is hacking or if you dont like that word, then experiment until you figure out how it works as no manual is completely correct/perfect.

Answer (score 2):

Jacob Beningo has a white paper that he created that describes the basics of creating API's for embedded work.  I would highly recommend reading this as a starting point: [Developing Reusable Device Drivers for MCUs](http://beningo.com/123-developing-reusable-device-drivers-for-mcus/).

His paper walks you through the design of API's for digital I/O and for SPI.  He describes why he makes a lot of the design decisions that he has made and has great tips on the use of pointer arrays, and configuration tables.  I found it very informative when I was starting out.

Of course, as Olaf and dwelch point out in the comments, you have to familiarize yourself with the datasheet in order to properly implement any of the peripherals of your MCU.